HI, I want to retrieve the total number of contacts from Salesforce Marketing Cloud
I want to retrieve the total number of contacts from Salesforce Marketing Cloud. I would like to do this using SoQL and Automation Studio, so that every month I can insert the total number of MKT contacts into a DE, but I am having difficulty finding out which table I should consult to get the total number of contacts. Can anyone help?
The issue with my problem is that I want to update the list with the number of contacts monthly automatically. This solution exists, but it does not automate.

You can also use the approach specified here, if you just need the count and not the actual contacts: https://digitalmarketingoncloud.com/contact-management/avoid-paying-too-much-for-your-contacts-in-marketing-cloud/

I found a solution, I saw that some people went through the same thing as me here, so I'll be sharing it, you must create a list like this guy teaches here and to automate it follow this step by step here
In summary, you create a list in Mobile Lists with the filter Contact Key is not null, create an automation that will 1- reset the list, so that it has the updated contacts, 2- through an SQL you will send the list data to a DE, 3- another SQL that will count the number of records there were in the previous DE.



